# How do I shift multiple columns? Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas

For simplicity sake, lets say I have this dataframe.

```
Date           Open    Close
2016-01-01     100     129
2016-01-02     198     193
2016-01-03     103     102
2016-01-04     102     109
```

I can't state all the column names because there are too many.  So how can I shift all the columns except for two of them (Date & Close)?  I want to shift all the columns except (Date & Close) back one row.

```
Date           Open    Close
2016-01-01     198     129
2016-01-02     103     193
2016-01-03     102     102
2016-01-04     NaN     109
```

Answer (score 16):

You could do it like this creating a mask for columns to exclude:

```
mask = ~(df.columns.isin(['Date','Close']))

cols_to_shift = df.columns[mask]

df[cols_to_shift] = df.loc[:,mask].shift(-1)
```

OR

```
df[cols_to_shift] = df[cols_to_shift].shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
         Date   Open  Close
0  2016-01-01  198.0    129
1  2016-01-02  103.0    193
2  2016-01-03  102.0    102
3  2016-01-04    NaN    109
```

Comment: 2 sec for real :-)

Comment: Great answer, but I'm curious about something. What's the deal with `:,mask`? A tuple probably, but of what and why?

Comment: @ManoelVilela You are correct, you could do df[cols_to_shift] = df[cols_to_shift].shift(-1) also.

Comment: Why is only Open shifted in your output? Shouldn't the close column also have 129 removed and with all values shifted up 1 and an NaN as the bottom row value?

Comment: the '~' is a not operator.  So True turn to  False and False turn to  True.

Answer (score 1):

Just use double brackets and insert the columns you want to shift.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],
                   [4,5,6],
                   [7,8,9]], columns = ['a','b','c'])
>>>
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9


df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].shift(-1)

>>>
     a    b  c
0  4.0  5.0  3
1  7.0  8.0  6
2  NaN  NaN  9
```