# Creating two shifted columns in grouped pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have looked all over and I still can't find an example of how to create two shifted columns in a Pandas Dataframe within its groups.

I have done it with one column as follows:

```
data_frame['previous_category'] = data_frame.groupby('id')['category'].shift()
```

But I have to do it with 2 columns, shifting one upwards and the other downwards.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I shift multiple columns? Pandas, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490505/how-do-i-shift-multiple-columns-pandas-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by custom function with [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), because one column need shift down and second shift up:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

def f(x):
    x['B'] = x['B'].shift()
    x['C'] = x['C'].shift(-1)
    return x

df = df.groupby('F').apply(f)
print (df)
     B    C  F
0  NaN  8.0  a
1  4.0  9.0  a
2  5.0  NaN  a
3  NaN  2.0  b
4  5.0  3.0  b
5  5.0  NaN  b
```

If want shift same way only specify all columns in lists:

```
df[['B','C']] = df.groupby('F')['B','C'].shift()
print (df)
     B    C  F
0  NaN  NaN  a
1  4.0  7.0  a
2  5.0  8.0  a
3  NaN  NaN  b
4  5.0  4.0  b
5  5.0  2.0  b
```

Comment: I have a question about this line: df[['B','C']] = df.groupby('F')['B','C'].apply(f). Does this apply a groupby on the entire df while applying the function, or are only the columns B and C grouped after this?

Comment: @Boris - only for filtered columns, but I add modification

Comment: @Boris - Tested and it should be simplify `df = df.groupby('F').apply(f)` - grouping by all values of groups