# Filling prior field based on grouped columns values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this

[image]

I want to move the value of desc and amount col a level up so that they start on the same row as the corresponding Number and Shipment Date value. This movement would be based on the corresponding group of Number and Shipment Date as below:

[image]

I think pandas ffill() and transform would be the main tools. So I am trying something like below:

```
df1=df.copy()

df1[['number', 'shipment_date']]=df1[['number', 'shipment_date']].ffill()
df1.desc=df1.desc.fillna('')
df1.amount= df1.amount.fillna('')

s= df1.groupby(['number', 'shipment_date']).amount.transform(lambda x: ' '.join(str(x)))

df.loc[df.shipment_date.notnull(),'amount']=s
df.loc[df.shipment_date.isnull(),'amount']=''
```

Problem is amount is float and it gives error even if coverted to str and trying to join as above.

And if I do the same for desc col, it would concatenate all the rows under number and shipment_date and join them together in same row instead of pulling one up.

Comment: You can use ``shift``, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47490612/4985099

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need select columns and then [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
cols = ['desc', 'amount']
df[cols] = df[cols].shift(-1)
```

Comment: Ok there is a problem. I didn't realize but I want the Fuel Surcharge value row to be next to the number, shipment_date value row. In the above, Fuel Surcharge is getting one row up but still not next to number, shipment_date if there are other values above it.

Comment: @Baktaawar - Is possible see data in text format with this problem?

Comment: sorry for late response. I have added a new Q for what I am actually looking for. Could u pls take a look? It has the data. Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62724022/filling-and-shifting-value-of-a-col-based-on-other-col-values