# Filling and shifting value of a col based on other col values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this

```
number  Shipment Date   service desc    amount
182692345   2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
            IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47
1827975839  2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    160.19
3229475633  2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
5733894261  29/04/2020  Express     
            DUTIES TAXES PAID   25
            FUEL SURCHARGE  3.28
1826995520  2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
2998455062  4/5/20  Express     
            FUEL SURCHARGE  0.72
```

In pic format it looks like below:

[image]

What I want is that for rows where number and shipment_date is present, we check the service where "Express" is there. Then for such rows I want to pull up the "Fuel Surcharge" row in desc col to the same row as number and `shipment_date` along with corresponding amount value.

So something like below:

```
number  Shipment Date   service desc    amount
182692345   2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
            IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47
1827975839  2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    160.19
3229475633  2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
5733894261  29/04/2020  Express FUEL SURCHARGE  3.28
            DUTIES TAXES PAID   25
                
1826995520  2/12/19 DUTIES & TAXES      
            IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47
            IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
2998455062  4/5/20  Express FUEL SURCHARGE  0.72
```

which looks like below in pic format.

[image]

In the end I only care about rows where service is "Express", so if we get rid of all rows where service is not express and get the format as above (only for Express values), that would be ideal.

I think pandas `ffill()` and transform would be the main tools. So I am trying something like below:

```
df1=df.copy()

df1[['number', 'shipment_date']]=df1[['number', 'shipment_date']].ffill()
df1.desc=df1.desc.fillna('')
df1.amount= df1.amount.fillna('')

s= df1.groupby(['number', 'shipment_date']).amount.transform(lambda x: ' '.join(str(x)))

df.loc[df.shipment_date.notnull(),'amount']=s
df.loc[df.shipment_date.isnull(),'amount']=''
```

Comment: What is not working in your current attempt at a solution?

Comment: I am not able to shift the Fuel Surcharge value for rows where "express" is present and shipment_date and number is present to same level as them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill a blank line with `fillna(method='ffill')`, extracted by the service, and obtained by `shift(-1)`. Does this fit the intent of the question?

```
df['service'] = df['service'].fillna(method='ffill')
df = df[df['service'] == 'Express']
df[['number','Shipment Date']] = df[['number','Shipment Date']].fillna(method='ffill')
df[['desc','amount']] = df[['desc','amount']].shift(-1)
df
    number  Shipment Date   service desc    amount
8   5.733894e+09    29/04/2020  Express DUTIES TAXES PAID   25.00
9   5.733894e+09    29/04/2020  Express FUEL SURCHARGE  3.28
10  5.733894e+09    29/04/2020  Express NaN NaN
14  2.998455e+09    4/5/20  Express FUEL SURCHARGE  0.72
15  2.998455e+09    4/5/20  Express NaN NaN
```

Comment: This keeps the FUEL SURCHARGE row on second. I want it to be flipped that FUEL SURCHARGE Row is on same row as the shipment_date and number. Check the output I showed above

Comment: The code has been updated as the 'FUEL SURCHARGE' and date need to be aligned.

Answer (score 1):

Logically you have a classic master / detail data set.  Your detail data set does not have foreign key to master record.  Add the FK then you can do filter conditions on master,  filter conditions on detail and join FK to PK

1. have modified source data to make it simple to construct DF from it
2. populate FK of detail records with `fillna`
3. select master and detail records and join them on PK / FK

```
import numpy as np
data = '''number  Shipment Date   service  desc    amount
182692345   2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES      
            -  -  IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
            -  -  IMPORT EXPORT TAXES  600.47
1827975839  2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES      
            -  -  IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    160.19
3229475633  2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES      
            -  -  IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47
            -  -  IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
5733894261  29/04/2020  Express     
            -  -  DUTIES TAXES PAID   25
            -  -  FUEL SURCHARGE  3.28
1826995520  2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES      
            -  -  IMPORT EXPORT TAXES  600.47
            -  -  IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES    561.01
2998455062  4/5/20  Express     
            -  -  FUEL SURCHARGE  0.72'''
da = [[i for i in re.split("[ ][ ]+", l)] for l in data.split("\n")]
dfall = pd.DataFrame(da[1:], columns=da[0])

dfall["number"][dfall["number"]==""] = np.NaN
dfall = dfall.fillna(method="ffill")
pd.concat([dfall[dfall["desc"]=="FUEL SURCHARGE"], dfmaster[dfall["service"]=="Express"] ], 
          join="inner", keys="number"
         ).sort_values(by=["number","service"], ascending=[True,False])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can forward filling missing values in `service` column, then compare for `Express` and last `shift` only matched rows and columns in list by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask = df['service'].ffill().eq('Express')
df.loc[mask, ['desc','amount']] = df.loc[mask, ['desc','amount']].shift(-1)
```

---

```
print (df)   
        number Shipment Date         service                        desc  \
0    182692345       2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES                               
1                        NaN             NaN        IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES   
2                        NaN             NaN         IMPORT EXPORT TAXES   
3   1827975839       2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES                               
4                        NaN             NaN        IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES   
5   3229475633       2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES                               
6                        NaN             NaN  IMPORT EXPORT TAXES 600.47   
7                        NaN             NaN        IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES   
8   5733894261    29/04/2020         Express           DUTIES TAXES PAID   
9                        NaN             NaN              FUEL SURCHARGE   
10                       NaN             NaN                               
11  1826995520       2/12/19  DUTIES & TAXES                               
12                       NaN             NaN         IMPORT EXPORT TAXES   
13                       NaN             NaN        IMPORT EXPORT DUTIES   
14  2998455062        4/5/20         Express              FUEL SURCHARGE   
15                       NaN             NaN                         NaN   

    amount  
0     None  
1   561.01  
2   600.47  
3     None  
4   160.19  
5     None  
6     None  
7   561.01  
8       25  
9     3.28  
10    None  
11    None  
12  600.47  
13  561.01  
14    0.72  
15     NaN
```